# Choose 3 elements from an Array List by conditions

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm making a java card game and now I try to create "a brain" for computer player. Conditions:

- on the table there are 3 cards (only value, not suit);
- computer player (CP) has 6 cards;
- to win a round CP has to beat at least 2 cards on the table, or it
  has to beat 1 card and make a draw with another 2 cards;
- of course, card set must be optimal.

Example:
on the table are cards with value 1, 2, 3. CP has cards with value 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6. It has to choose card with value 2 to beat Card1, than choose card with value 3 to beat Card2 and than choose card with value 1, because it has already beat 2 cards.
Now i wrote the next code, but it's not working true or not working at all.

```
for (i = 0, j = i++, k = j++; i < oppHand.size() - 2 && j < oppHand.size() - 1 && k < oppHand.size(); i++) {

a = oppHand.get(i).getPower(); //value of card1 from CP hand
b = oppHand.get(j).getPower(); //value of card2 from CP hand
c = oppHand.get(k).getPower(); //value of card3 from CP hand

x = oppHand.indexOf(i);        //position of card1 in a CP hand
y = oppHand.indexOf(j);        //position of card2 in a CP hand
z = oppHand.indexOf(k);        //position of card3 in a CP hand

if (a > Score1 && b > Score2 ||  a> Score1 && c > Score3) {    //Score - value of the cards on the table
choice1 = x;
choice2 = y;
choice3 = z;}

else if (a > Score1 && b > Score3 || a > Score1 && c > Score2) {
choice1 = x;
choice2 = z;
choice3 = y;} ........

// moving cards from the CP hand to the table with assignment values to the piles
    validPower5 = oppHand.get(choice1).getPower();  
    discardPile5.add(0, oppHand.get(choice1));
    oppHand.remove(choice1);

    validPower6 = oppHand.get(choice2).getPower();  
    discardPile6.add(0, oppHand.get(choice2));
    oppHand.remove(choice2);

    validPower7 = oppHand.get(choice3).getPower();  
    discardPile7.add(0, oppHand.get(choice3));
    oppHand.remove(choice3);
                    }
```

Comment: "not working true or not working at all" doesn't give any clue for us to work on. Give more detail.

Comment: we can't help you at programming the logic, just try to tell us where you are lost at, and we will try to point you to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

would something like this help?

```
sortCardsOnTable();//now Score1 <= Score2 <= Score2
sortOpponentCards();
boolean beatScore1 = false;
boolean beatScore2 = false;
int indexFirst = 0;
int indexSecond = 0;
int indexThird = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < oppHand.size();i++){
   Card c = oppHand.get(i);
   if(!beatScore1 && c.getPower() > Score1){
      indexFirst = i;
      beatScore1 = true;
   }
   else if(beatScore1 && c.getPower() > Score2){
      indexSecond = i;
      beatScore2 = true;
      indexThird = 1;//here compare with indexFirst so you dont pull the first card twice, just pull the first available card
   }
}
```

you should sort your Cardlist, to simplify the computation

Answer (score 0):

I think you if else condition need to be correct..

Not sure but check this code for that.

```
if (a > Score1) 
{    //Score - value of the cards on the table
    if (b > Score2 || c > Score3)   {
        choice1 = x;
        choice2 = y;
        choice3 = z;    }
    else if (b > Score3 || c > Score2)  {
        choice1 = x;
        choice2 = y;
        choice3 = z;    }
}
```

I think this should work ...